# Order of spline variable in comparing nested model fitted to imputed data using mice::pool.compare

Tags: r, regression, data-imputation, splines

I have been encountered an issue when comparing two nested models fitted to imputed data using `mice::pool.compare`. The obtained p-value depends on the position of variable (in spline form) in the model's formula. Let's take an example:
Order 1:

```
imp <- mice(nhanes2)
mi1 <- with(data=imp, expr=lm(bmi~age+hyp+ns(chl,2)))
mi0 <- with(data=imp, expr=lm(bmi~age+hyp+chl))
pc  <- pool.compare(mi1, mi0, method='Wald')
pc$pvalue
```

Order 2:

```
mi1 <- with(data=imp, expr=lm(bmi~ns(chl,2)+age+hyp))
mi0 <- with(data=imp, expr=lm(bmi~chl+age+hyp))
pc  <- pool.compare(mi1, mi0, method='Wald')
pc$pvalue
```

The two orders give different p-value without any error message from R.
I have two questions:
1- Which order is the correct one in term of yielding reliable p-value for model comparison
2- Why in `mice::pool.compare()` variables in submodel have to be in the same order as in the larger model.

Comment: The p-values _are_ dependent on the order of entry in a model. It is really dependent on the comparison of models and the actual hypotheses under consideration. The notion that p-values should always be independent of order entry come from a a disputed expectation due to  SAS (in the form of their default use of so-called type III sums of errors) that this should not be the case.  _You_  should give a clear statement of the statistical questions. NOT a coding question. You need statistical advice. Alternate perspective: https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS3/Exegeses.pdf